# Getting variable value from the REST response code(SoapUI)

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

This is the response(as XML) I get from TestCase1 when I run my REST request:

```
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="88">
    <![CDATA[{"message":"success","data":{"export_id":"064c1948fe238d892fcda0f87e361400_1467676599"}}]]>
</data>
```

I want to use the value of export_id(dynamic) which is `064c1948fe238d892fcda0f87e361400_1467676599` in the Test Case 2.

How Can I achieve this? I tried using property transfer but I am not sure how to configure.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [tutorial on the property transfer](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) yet? I'm not sure though if you can extract the `export_id` from the embedded JSON easily with this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you have is complex, not just an `xml` to extract the required value using property transfer. Because, it contains `cdata` and it internally again contains `json` and you need the value which is inside the of it.

So, in order to get that value, need to use `Groovy Script` test step instead of `Property Transfer` test step. Having said that, you remove the Property Transfer and have Groovy Script step in the same place.

And the contents of the **Groovy Script** goes here:

[image]

```groovy
/**
* This script reads a response xml string, extracts cdata at the specified xpath
* Then parse that string as Json and extract the required value
**/
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
//For testing using fixed value as you mentioned in the question
//However, you can use the dynamic response as well which is coming from the 
//previous step as well if you want
def soapResponse = '''
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="88"><![CDATA[{
           "message":"success",
           "data": 
           {
               "export_id":"064c1948fe238d892fcda0f87e361400_1467676599"
           }
      }]]>
</data>'''
def holder = new XmlHolder(soapResponse)
//Extract the data inside of CDATA section from the response
def data = holder.getNodeValue('//*:data')
//Parse the string with JsonSlurper
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
log.info json
//Extract the export_id
def exportId =  json.data."export_id"
log.info "Export id : ${exportId}"
//Since you wanted to use the extracted value in another test case,
//Saving the value at test suite level custom property EXPORT_ID
//So that it can be used in any of the test case once the value is set
context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('EXPORT_ID', exportId)
```

**How to use the `export_id` value in other test cases?**

- If you want to use the value in a `(REST / SOAP) Test Request` test step, then you can simple use it using property expansion i.e., `${#TestSuite#EXPORT_ID}`.
- If you want to use the value in a `Groovy Script` test step, then you need get the value using `log.info context.expand('${#TestSuite#EXPORT_ID}')`

**How to use dynamic response in the Groovy Script?**

As mentioned in the in-line comments in the script above, I have shown how to get the required value using your sample data.

But it may be difficult for you to each time replace the value for variable `soapRespone` in the script or you may also want to automate the stuff as well.

In such cases, you just need to replace `def soapResponse` statement with below code :

```
//Replace the previous step request test step name in place of "Test Request"
//Where you get the response which needs to be proceed in the groovy script
def soapResponse = context.expand('${Test Request#Response}')
```

Comment: Glad to know that it helped.